# How do I change the width of my image in my theme Bludit?

Tags: html, css, content-management-system

I am working on a new CMS called bludit. I have chosen a theme for this cms but I still have to modify it a bit. Right now, I’m trying to make the image take the full width of the screen : [Visuel site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrNGi.jpg)

Here you can see the code for the original header image :

```
<section class="page">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="content-card">

                <!-- Page cover image -->
                <?php if ($page->coverImage()): ?>
                <div class="page-cover-image mb-4"
                    style="background-image: url('<?php echo $page->coverImage(); ?>');">
                    <div style="height: 400px;"></div>
                </div>
                <?php endif ?>
```

As I try to make the image take all the width but that the text below keeps these dimensions, I logically tried to get the div out of the image of the container as well as this col-lg-8. Here’s what I tried:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- for the image take all the width -->
            <div class="containerImage col-lg-12">
                <div class="header-image">
                    <div class="contenu">

                        <!-- Page cover image -->
                        <?php if ($page->coverImage()): ?>
                            <div class="page-cover-image mb-4"
                            style="background-image: url('<?php echo $page->coverImage(); ?>');">
                            <div style="height: 400px;"></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.page-cover-image {
    width: 100%;
}

.contenu {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But I don’t understand why there is no effect... Anyone has an idea of the problem? Maybe an left margin specific to CMS? Probably I made a mistake...

Thank you very much in advance.

```
          Sofia R.
```

Comment: Please put your actual code in your question. It is very tedious for us to have to visit all the links.

Answer (score 0):

The image has already a width of 100%. It's part of different `div` defining the width.

If you would like to have a greater width, you have to modify the theme, which uses Bootstrap.